# What's the proper way to regenerate cmake files after modifying a cache variable?

Tags: cmake

e.g.

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DSOME_OPTS ..
$ ninja
$ vim CMakeCache.txt
(... edit a cache variable)
```

what now is the proper command to use to regenerate the build files? I've been using `cmake ..` but I just did so and it produced considerably more steps to rebuild than I had anticipated.

Answer (score -3):

You are doing it wrongly. In brief, never ever edit CMakeCache.txt manually!

If necessary, edit CMakeLists.txt and  cmake will take care of changes during build step automatically.

Also, if you need to make changes to already configured build, without changing CMakeLists.txt, you might use cmake-gui from build directory:

```
cmake-gui .
```

note one dot as a parameter to cmake-gui;  this will allow you to edit/change configuration very comfortably, and cmake will take care of applying the changes. Take care, you must initiate (i.e. press button) **configre**, followed by **generate** within cmake-gui, in order to save changes you made.